# Flutter continuous integration (CI) not working on github because the project is inside a folder

Tags: flutter, dart, continuous-integration, yaml, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to implement continuous integration on my github repository.
If the project is at the same level as root, it works. But I want to have the project inside a folder to keep it organized. On my local setup, I would do "cd my_folder", but I tried to add that to the .yml script and still fails.

Error shown:

```
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Basically it fails because it's trying to do pub get at the root of the repository where pubspec.yaml doesn't exist, instead of inside of the folder.

This is the code:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - development

jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '12.x'
    - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      with:
          channel: 'beta'
   # Enter into the flutter project.
    - run: cd my_folder # Here I tried to put this command, but is useless
          
   # Get flutter dependencies.
    - run: flutter pub get # <--- Here is the error
    
    # Statically analyze the Dart code for any errors.
    - run: flutter analyze .
    
    # Run widget tests for our flutter project.
    - run: flutter test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, just needed to add a working-directory

Final code

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - development

jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '12.x'
    - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      with:
          channel: 'beta'
         
    - name: Get flutter dependencies
      run: flutter pub get
      working-directory: my_folder
    
    - name: Statically analyze the Dart code for any errors.
      run: flutter analyze .
      working-directory: my_folder
    
    - name: Run widget tests for our flutter project.
      run: flutter test
      working-directory: my_folder
```

Answer (score 0):

This error tells you that there is no pubspec.yaml in your development branch, try to push your pubspec.yaml to the development branch.